# xslt xml parsing optional keywords with variable text groups

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I have a snippet:

```
<p>keyword1 text text more text
</p>
<p>more text</p>
<p>more text</p>
<p>keyword2 text text more text
</p>
<p>more text</p>
<p>more text</p>
<p>keyword3 text text more text
</p>
<p>more text</p>
<p>more text</p>
<p>keyword4 
</p>
</body>
```

In the snippet above, I have a list of optional keywords. The text which follows is of variable length.    There might be multiple groupings of `<p></p>` before the next keyword appears.  When the next keyword appears, it signals the end of the previous keyword.

Whats a good way to go about doing this in XSLT.

edit:
suppose my keywords were: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4

version 1.0

i'll post my xslt in a little while... its not working though

Comment: You have posted an input sample to illustrate the input you have, please also post the matching, desired output sample you want to create for that input with XSLT. And tell us whether you want to use XSLT 2.0 or 1.0 as 2.0 has much better support for grouping and text processing.

Comment: It appears that a piece of the input is still missing: the list of the keywords that need to be recognized in the input provided. Where will this list be found and in what form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the XSLT 2.0 grouping constructs, with a `group-starts-with` attribute that returns true for each p element containing a keyword.

That is, something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="keywords" 
  as="xs:string*"
  select="('keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3', 'keyword4')"
  />
<xsl:for-each-group select="p"
  group-starting-with="tokenize(., '\s+') = $keywords">

  <!--* process each group here ... *-->

</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear what kind of result you intend to get.

C.M. Sperberg's approach addresses the right basic idea, however the code provided seems not to run with my XSL processor. So I'd propose a transformation like this

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

  <xsl:variable name="keywords" select="'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 keyword4'"/>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with="p[contains($keywords,substring-before(.,' '))]">
        <div>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(current-group()[1],' ')"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Be careful with `contains()` because it's easy to get a false positive with a partial match.